# number of arguments in Power Query custom function

Tags: powerquery

guys!

I tried to create my custom function in Power Query and came across very unexpected and totally non-clear to me Err.

Function is simple -- it retrieves Name of the Student from Students Dictionary (it is called from Students Dictionary Table), then it retrieves tables of invoices and calculates how many invoieces were issued to this paticular Student.

code of the function is as following:

```
    (FirstName as text) =>

let
    Source = XeroInvoices,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([XeroContacts.Name], FirstName) ),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"XeroContacts.Name"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"XeroContacts.Name"}, {{"Result", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
    Result = Record.Field(#"Grouped Rows", {0}, "Result")
in
    Result
```

Yet, as I call function with one argument, it says that ***three*** arguments were passed, and that the function expected ***two***:

http://shot.qip.ru/00Qqzx-4Vmk2GJfF/

Could you please suggest what can be the problem with this all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The function that is causing the error-message is probably the last step of your function above:

Result = Record.Field(#"Grouped Rows", {0}, "Result")

It takes only 2 arguments: The record and the name of the field you want to catch. So try changing it to :

Result = Record.Field(#"Grouped Rows"{0}, "Result")

Find a tip on how to easily debug your M-functions [here](http://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/05/30/analyze-m-functions-step-step/).

Comment: Hey, ImkeF!
Thanks for your answer.
I tried it but it didn't help.

Now it says that one argument was passed to the function that requires two:
http://shot.qip.ru/00Qqzx-3Vmk2GJgY/
/////////
http://shot.qip.ru/00Qqzx-2Vmk2GJgZ/

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It's not working for you now because you have further modified your original function. In the very first row where you pass the parameters to the function, you've added another parameter: "SecondName". So now when you call the function, you have to pass just that parameter into the function as well: fnFindFirstStudent([First Name], [Second Name]). But I have my doubts that you will be happy with the results as many of the second names are empty and you have combined them with an "and". Consider merging these fields before.

Comment: dear ImkeF)
now I got back to this pattern and evaluated your answer) Thanks a lot, this was the issue. Now function works perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple way:

```
(FirstName as text) =>
    let
        Source = XeroInvoices,
        FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([XeroContacts.Name], FirstName) ),
        Result = List.Count(FilteredTable[XeroContacts.Name])
    in
        Result
```

Comment: Thanks, Eugene
this looks much more short and indeed much more simple